# Lisp-style quotation in HTML

Tags: html, lisp

In Lisp, evaluating '(+ 1 2) produces '(+ 1 2), not 3. It seems that HTML doesn't support Lisp-style quotation so you can't say something like <quote><b>not bold</b></quote> in HTML and let it just produce <b>not bold</b> instead of **not bold**.

Is there any technical reason or historical reason for that? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not asking why Lisp has this quotation; I was just thinking it could make certain escapeHtml tasks(e.g., escaping {&, <, >, ...}) easier if HTML support Lisp-style quotation

Answer (score 6):

HTML has nothing to do with Lisp and did not derivate from it, so there's no reason that particular syntax should behave that way. You can, however, include literal representations of HTML tags in your markup by substituting the < and > signs with their HTML entities, like this:

`&lt;b&gt;not bold&lt;/b&gt;`

This will produce:

<b>not bold</b>

Comment: I of course know the HTML entities, that's why you can see &lt;b&gt;not bold&lt;/b&gt; in my own post. But the point of my questions is: I think the Lisp way is more WYSIWYG, rather than the entity-encoding way.

Answer (score 5):

You can quote markup in any SGML/XML dialect using a [CDATA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA) section like this:

`<![CDATA[<b>not bold</b>]]>`

Answer (score 0):

**code is data data is code.**

[Check this out](http://www.defmacro.org/ramblings/lisp.html). It might help you some.

Comment: See my comment to my own post